# populating dropdown with values from xml file in php

Tags: php, xml

I want to make a dropdown list with the values from inside the xml file. The dropdown is present but it is blank on the web. Why? Is there something i've missed?

I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    echo "<select>";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('curs.xml');
            foreach ($xml->item as $item)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$item->name."'></option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
</form>
```

The code for the xml file:

```
<prod>

<item>
    <name>Cheese</name>
    <price>4.25</price>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Milk</name>
    <price>8.12</price>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Egg</name>
    <price>0.81</price>
</item>

</prod>
```

Comment: You don't have anything in the option. `<option value="foo">Foo</option>

Comment: Works here: http://codepad.org/iEug9Lc4 You must have a path problem to the xml file. Use the absolute path, e.g. `/home/sites/www/resources/curs.xml` (or whatever it is). EDIT: I've just noticed you're not printing the values *within* the `<option>` tags either, so they'll appear blank. See: http://codepad.org/XArgKuSq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($xml->item as $item)
{
   echo "<option value='".$item->name."'>" . $item->name . "</option>";
}
```

The visible part of an `<option>` is what you put between `<option>` and `</option>`

Comment: That's so right, i've missed this part and I thought something is wrong with the code. I am newbie. Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars exists for a reason ;) And take care that simplexml returns UTF-8, that should be also the encoding of the HTML file then.

Comment: I have no idea what he is on about

Comment: I guess it is about compatibility between the xml and html... just saying!